# How to pass Django template variables to a WebPack module

Tags: javascript, python, django, webpack

I am just learning about WebPack module, and I am thinking of moving the entire JS infrastructure of my Django app to modules. It seems that a straightforward way of doing this is to create a webpack module for each Django template (or view), and have a single `<script>` tag on each page.

However, I'm trying to find a way of passing the content of Django template variables to these webpack modules. Previously I could have these variables inlined:

```
<script>
//Sample code..
var arr = [];
{% for s in vars %}
arr.push(s);
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Now, I only have:

```
<script src="temp.js"></script>
```

One potential solution I found is to define the webpack module to be a library that exports a single root function to the global namespace in the browser. Then use an inline `script` tag to put the Django variables into a JS variable, and pass this as arguments to the exported function.

This somehow feels like a clumsy way of doing things. Any ideas as to how I can handle this better?

Thanks!

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I am writing a plugin for another system using React (I really like that this was made easy to do compared to say Ember which likes to control the whole show) which uses django templating. The plugin extension points relied on a couple of templated values. I built my webpack bundle as a library and exported a single function which takes as arguments, the missing templated values. I'm completely agreed that it feels very clumsy, but I think that we're merging two fundamentally different approaches so it is kinda to be expected!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I've done it, based on dpwrussel's hint in the question's comments and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858050/webpack-export-function):

In my module that I'm importing, I do this:

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

window.render_my_thing = function(properties) {
    ReactDOM.render(...)
}
```

Then in my django template, I add the following:

```
<script>                                                                        
  render_my_thing({
      property1: "{{ property1 }}",
      property2: "{{ property2 }}",
  })                                                                
</script>
```