# How to export a symbol from a webpack bundle to use in another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

There are some JS modules which I'd like to use on the browser. I have created a webpack project for that. However I am unable to use them in my target JS file.

I'd like to create a bundle that I could use like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='ndarray-bundle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
let ndx = ndarray(x, x_dims.slice(0)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For that I creates a folder with the following webpack and package.json files:

Webpack file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'ndarray-bundle.js'
  }
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "packstuff-js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Just so I can pack ndarray stuff as one JS file",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://nothing/"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ndarray"
  ],
  "author": "jeff",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "ndarray": "^1.0.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I run webpack and get a bundled file however everytime I ran that I get the following error:
`ndarray is not defined`

I have used the following index.js contents all to no avail:

version 1:

```
import ndarray from 'ndarray';
```

version 2:

```
require('ndarray');
export const ndarray = 'ndarray';
```

version 3:

```
const ndarray = require('ndarray');
```

version 4:

```
export ndarray from 'ndarray';
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice here and defined global variables:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37862805/5669031

My index.js now looks like:

```
import ndarray from 'ndarray';

window.ndarray = ndarray;
```